# Qt4: Making fullscreen window impossible to get around (a lock screen)?

Tags: c++, qt4, xorg, lockscreen

My application is an OS lock screen (like GDM's lock screen or KDE's), so I'm trying to make it function like one.

I am trying to make my application's window hover above *all* other windows and disable/intercept all keyboard shortcuts (`ALT-TAB`, `CTRL-ALT-D`, etc.) that would cause it disappear.

Is there any way to do this? I'm 100% sure there is, as lock screens with GUIs exist, but I just can't find the place to look...

Comment: I would consider it a bug in the windowing system or desktop environment if it allowed arbitrary applications to take over in this way. I guess some games might do it, but at the very least you should still be able to use Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to a text console.

Comment: @OrbWeaver, consider this question to be asking how to create a lock screen. Such programs already exist; what is it about them that lets them work? Maybe it's a certain API they need to use to tell the WM or OS that the screen is locked, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with Qt, but what you are looking for is called [grabbing](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-6.html#s-6). You can grab the [pointer input device](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/pointer-grabbing.html) as well as the [keyboard](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/keyboard-grabbing.html%2a).

**Edit:** Looking in to the Qt4 docs, have you tried to use [QWidget::grabMouse](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#grabMouse)? It looks like this function does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll be fiddling with these.

Comment: I managed to use `XGrabServer` to completely lock the server, but my window is unresponsive. I can move the mouse cursor around, but the lock screen is also dead...

Comment: *(facepalm)*. Why didn't I look through the Qt4 documentation for mouse and keyboard grabbing beforehand...? Either way, my application works (almost) perfectly with `grabKeyboard()` and `grabMouse()`. I just have to give *all* of the widgets access to the mouse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but you can try an event handler using `QObject::installEventFilter()`.

If you are using Windows, you can install an event filter that handles messages where `event->type() == QEvent::WinEventAct`.

I don't really know much about other OSs, but Qt probably has something for that too.

Answer (score 0):

inherit `Qwidget` class with parameter `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` see below

```
myclass::myclass(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent,Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```