# Grabbing input using qt4

Tags: c++, qt4, x11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qt4: Making fullscreen window impossible to get around (a lock screen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793728/qt4-making-fullscreen-window-impossible-to-get-around-a-lock-screen)

I want to write a screen lock using c++/qt4. I am done with the authentication part, that is I can verify the entered key. The graphical part of the program is one widget which inherits from QWidget directly. I now need to make sure of the following:

1. The window should be in fullscreen. At the moment I make sure of this by using the "showFullScreen()" method instead of the normal show() mathod of QWidget.
2. It should be impossible to terminate the application. To this end I have written a sigterm handler function which does nothing. I also told the widget to ignore close events, which seems to work fine
3. I also need to make sure that users can't alt+tab away from the window. I don't know how to do that using qt4. I tried setting the Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint option. This does however not work with the showFullScreen() method. It also has the drawback that even if the window stays on top, the user can still alt+tab away.

I would appreciate it if it were possible to achieve this last goal by only using qt. Alternatively I would also appreciate hints about how to do this by talking directly to X if it doesn't work with qt alone.